# JavaFX 2.2: Applying color effect on ImageView resizes back to image dimensions

Tags: colors, resize, imageview, javafx, effect

I create an imageView and resize it. After applying a color effect it gets resized back to original dimensions.

Envi: Oracle JDK 7 (1.7.0_51-b13) and Oracle JDK 8 (8b124-0~webupd8~0)

```
final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
imageView.setFitHeight(image.getHeight() * imageViewScale);
imageView.setFitWidth(image.getWidth() * imageViewScale);
```

Resizing works fine until now. But colorizing it resizes back to embedded image dimensions.

```
final Blend effect = new Blend(BlendMode.SRC_ATOP, new ImageInput(imageView.getImage()), new ColorInput(0, 0, imageView.getImage().getWidth(), imageView.getImage().getHeight(), color));
imageView.setEffect(effect);
```

Even a later resetting does not work

```
imageView.setFitHeight(height);
imageView.setFitWidth(width);
```

I already tried the approach of the ImageViewPane in https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-21337 but it could not handle the case as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: For sure: A silly workaround might be to replace the imageView by a new one using the Image Constructor with specification of width and height. But that is not the way it should work, I think. Still wondering about this strange behaviour...